# Intution for knowing when a multivariate limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

In general, is there an intutive way to "know" when a multivariate limit exists/does not exist? I know that I can use trial-and-error with some paths of approach to show that it does not exist, but often this takes significant time, and is not that feasible under exam conditions.

For e.g., if this were a rational expression (i.e., ignore the log term) of polynomials in both the denominator and numerator, then I could compare degrees, and have an "intuition" that the bottom degree of 6 will "shrink faster" than the top, causing me to think that the limit does not exist.

Can I generalise this intution to non-rational functions? i.e., a very hairy composition of several functions in both the denominator and numerator. Or perhaps a function that's not even in the form of a fraction.

Comment: In some cases (for example in the case you provide) you can replace a complicated looking function by a suitable asymptote to simplify the calculations. For example, $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$, so you can actually justify that the question of limit existence in the example you give is equal to the question of limit existence for the function $\frac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^6}$, which is easier to understand than the first limit.

Comment: Finding those asymptotes requires you to consider the Taylor expansion of the function (in this case $\ln(1+x)$) at the limit point $0$ and see the lowest power of $x$ whose coefficient is non-zero.

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$, then why is the new function that you're considering $\frac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^6}$ rather than $\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^6}$?

Comment: Because if $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$, then you can write $$ \frac{x^2y^3\ln(1+x)}{x^4+y^6} = \frac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^6} \times \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x},$$ and the second fraction has limit equal to $1$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ (it doesn't depend upon $y$), so the two fractions must have the same limit (or both limits must not exist simultaneously). That is basically what I was saying.